# Проблема с file_get_contents

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Вечер добрый. Не могу понять почему при отправке текста на стену в группу через метод wall.post, выводиться ошибка, точнее PHP Warring на линии самого запроса, который выглядит так:

```
$post_upload = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=-{$group_id}&from_group=1&message={$donor_wall_text}&attachments={$attachments}&access_token={$bot_access_token}&v=5.92"));
```

Я протестировал, 759 символов отправляет хорошо пост публикуется, но когда ставишь 760 символов в тексте, то всё ошибка, пост на стену не попадает.

Есть у кого какие мысли на этот счет?

Система debian 9, nginx, php7

Comment: курлом через метод post пробуйте отправить

Comment: А что за варнинг конечно нельзя рассказать, так как военная тайна?

Comment: @Solo_777 Спасибо помогло!